# How can i output every Day inside my Daterange?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to output a Range of Dates. I know how to get the Starting Date and the End Date, thanks to a tutorial but i dont know how to show the Days between those.

I thought it would be enough if I copy the Code and just delete the picker.endDate.format or picker.startDate.format so i just have picker.Date.format but that didnt work.

This is my Datepicker and my Input and Output Fields

My Date Field with Cakephp

```php
echo $this->Form->control('dates', array('label' => __('Datum',true), 'empty' => true));
```

The Input Fields for the Dates (at the Moment only 3 but i wish to output 7 Days)

```html
<input id="selectedDatePickerField" /><br><br />
<input id="selectedDatePickerField2" /><br><br />
```

The Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $('input[name="dates"]').daterangepicker({
   "maxSpan": {
        "days": 7
    },
      autoUpdateInput: false,
      "locale": {
        "format": "DD/MM/YYYY",
        "separator": " - ",
        "applyLabel": "Bestätigen",
        "cancelLabel": "Abbrechen",
        "fromLabel": "From",
        "toLabel": "To",
        "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
        "weekLabel": "W",
        "daysOfWeek": [
            "So",
            "Mo",
            "Di",
            "Mi",
            "Do",
            "Fr",
            "Sa"
        ],
        "monthNames": [
            "Januar",
            "Februar",
            "März",
            "April",
            "Mai",
            "Juni",
            "Juli",
            "August",
            "September",
            "Oktober",
            "November",
            "Dezember"
        ],
        "firstDay": 1
    },
  });

    $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#dates').on('change', function () {
    $('#selectedDatePickerField').val(this.value);
    $('#selectedDatePickerField2').val(this.value);
  }).change();
  $('#dates').on('daterangepicker', function (e, ui) {
    $('#selectedDatePickerField').val(ui.item.value);
    $('#selectedDatePickerField2').val(ui.item.value);
  });
});

$('input[name="dates"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $('#selectedDatePickerField').val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));     
  $('#selectedDatePickerField2').val(picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));

});
  $('input[name="dates"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
  });

  $('input[name="dates"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val('');
  });

});
```

So what do I need to do, that I can output all 7 Days from my Daterange?
I want to create them in an input field so i can work with them later and know on which Date which Menu got ordered.

Im still new to coding, so if i missed anything just tell me and i will edit my Question.

**EDIT**
Im sorry for my bad wording, my Goal is to output all Dates from a Range.
Example:

Daterange: 03.07.2019 - 09.07.2019


Dates:

03.07.2019
04.07.2019
05.07.2019
06.07.2019
07.07.2019
08.07.2019
09.07.2019

At the End i want to use it too show 7 Days. I just tryed it with 3 Outputs to understand how it works. Hope its a little bit clearer now.

**EDIT 2**

So the cakephp thing is an Input Field which just looks like this:

```html
<input type="text" name="datefilter" value="" />
```

Its just another way to write it. Sorry for the Confusion there. 

I just used this Tutorial to create the Fields for the Daterange: http://www.daterangepicker.com/#example5

The other Input ids:

```html
<input id="selectedDatePickerField" /><br><br />
<input id="selectedDatePickerField2" /><br><br />
```

show the FirstDate and the LastDate i picked with the Daterangepicker. Now i try to output not only the FistDate and LastDate but the Days between then, like shown in my Example.

Comment: TBH, not sure what you're asking - you want all the dates between two dates, but you have 3 or 7 inputs or just 1 input?  If you have start/end dates, then listing all dates between isn't difficult, but it's not clear if that's what you're after.

Comment: I edited my Question to make it clearer what my Goal is. Sorry for my bad explaining at the start!

Comment: Are you trying to create 7 date input using cakephp?

Comment: Yes I created the Datefield to pick my Daterange with cakephp. Now i just want to ouput every Day from my Daterange, into the new Fields. The Maximum Dates you can pick are 7, thats why i want to output a max of 7 Fields (= Dates).

Comment: I asked if you want to create 7 inputs, you replied "yes" and then details that imply "*no*".   It's not clear if you're trying to create 7 inputs with cakephp or if you have 1 (or 2?) inputs (as implied by your html) and then what you want to do with the 3 or 7 dates between those dates.  Is it safe to say the cakephp part is a red-herring and not relevant?  Is this the scenario: you have 2 date inputs, then, when the user clicks a button you want to create more date inputs for the dates between the original 2?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are after: https://jsfiddle.net/87guaq40/

Comment: I edited my Question again to make it a little clearer what i did. Because your fiddle is going into the right direction but i dont have 2 input fields i only have one which picks the range of the Dates. Example: 03/06/2019 - 09/06/2019

Comment: The source of the dates appears to immaterial - it's what you do with the dates that seems to be the crux of the question - perhaps this is clearer: https://jsfiddle.net/sr1ju934/